# for each in for each logic

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to do following in XSLT 1.0:

Copy all the Fram element as is into output, where the condition is any of Fram's attributes (@name AND @type AND @ref) value matches with any XFram element then it should update the Fram/text() with XFram/text(). After that copy rest of XFram element (all those dint match the above criteria) and convert them into Fram tag.

Note: Third Fram element's all attribute matches with third Xfram element, hence text appended in Third Fram element. Rest of XFarm element got transform into Fram element and added after last Fram element. Also you will notice that Fram's order is not changed.

Input.XML

```
<Doc>AL
<Frams>
 <Fram type="x" name="Fram1" ref="ref1">This is Fram One</Fram>
 <Fram type="y" name="Fram2" ref="ref2">This is Fram Two</Fram>
 <Fram type="z" name="Fram3" ref="ref3">This is Fram Three</Fram>
 <Fram type="a" name="Fram4" ref="ref3">This is Fram Four</Fram>
 <Fram type="b" name="Fram5" ref="ref3">This is Fram Five</Fram>
</Frams>
<XFram>
 <XFram type="e" name="XFram1" ref="Xref1">This is XFram One</Fram>
 <XFram type="f" name="XFram2" ref="Xref2">This is XFram Two</Fram>
 <XFram type="z" name="XFram3" ref="Xref3">This is XFram Three</Fram>
 <XFram type="e" name="XFram1" ref="Xref1">This is XFram Four</Fram>
<XFram>
<Doc>
```

Output should be:

```
<Doc>
 <Frams>
 <Fram type="x" name="Fram1" ref="ref1">This is Fram One</Fram>
 <Fram type="y" name="Fram2" ref="ref2">This is Fram Two</Fram>
 <Fram type="z" name="Fram3" ref="ref3">This is XFram Three</Fram>
 <Fram type="a" name="Fram4" ref="ref3">This is Fram Four</Fram>
 <Fram type="b" name="Fram5" ref="ref3">This is Fram Five</Fram>
 <XFram type="e" name="XFram1" ref="Xref1">This is XFram One</Fram>
 <XFram type="f" name="XFram2" ref="Xref2">This is XFram Two</Fram>
 <XFram type="e" name="XFram1" ref="Xref1">This is XFram Four</Fram>
 </Frams>
<Doc>
```

I am doing something like this but not able to think of the logic:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="XFram">
        <xsl:variable name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="ref">
            <xsl:value-of select="ref"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="//Fram">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(type = $type) and (name = $name) and (ref = $ref)"> </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>           
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Fram[last()]">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>

  <xsl:apply-templates
       select="../../XFram/*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="XFram/XFram">
  <xsl:if test=
   "not(/*/Frams/*
             [@type = current()/@type
            and
              concat('X',@name) = current()/@name
            and
              concat('X',@ref) = current()/@ref
             ]
         )">
     <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="XFram"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (with corrected severe malformedness!!!):

```
<Doc>
    <Frams>
        <Fram type="x" name="Fram1" ref="ref1">This is Fram One</Fram>
        <Fram type="y" name="Fram2" ref="ref2">This is Fram Two</Fram>
        <Fram type="z" name="Fram3" ref="ref3">This is Fram Three</Fram>
        <Fram type="a" name="Fram4" ref="ref3">This is Fram Four</Fram>
        <Fram type="b" name="Fram5" ref="ref3">This is Fram Five</Fram>
    </Frams>
    <XFram>
        <XFram type="e" name="XFram1" ref="Xref1">This is XFram One</XFram>
        <XFram type="f" name="XFram2" ref="Xref2">This is XFram Two</XFram>
        <XFram type="z" name="XFram3" ref="Xref3">This is XFram Three</XFram>
        <XFram type="e" name="XFram1" ref="Xref1">This is XFram Four</XFram></XFram>
</Doc>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<Doc>
   <Frams>
      <Fram type="x" name="Fram1" ref="ref1">This is Fram One</Fram>
      <Fram type="y" name="Fram2" ref="ref2">This is Fram Two</Fram>
      <Fram type="z" name="Fram3" ref="ref3">This is Fram Three</Fram>
      <Fram type="a" name="Fram4" ref="ref3">This is Fram Four</Fram>
      <Fram type="b" name="Fram5" ref="ref3">This is Fram Five</Fram>
      <XFram type="e" name="XFram1" ref="Xref1">This is XFram One</XFram>
      <XFram type="f" name="XFram2" ref="Xref2">This is XFram Two</XFram>
      <XFram type="e" name="XFram1" ref="Xref1">This is XFram Four</XFram>
   </Frams>
</Doc>
```